# JQuery not rendering correctly

Tags: php, jquery, html

Currently, I have a jquery function that I'm trying to get to display the time (the jquery I'm using is the Basic Example found here: http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/). When I implement Mr. Thornton's timepicker, I may click on the input field and a list of time options drops down, however there is no scroll bar/slider on the side of the drop down (as there is in his example). The time value that I select (I can use the mouse scroller to move up and down in the selection) is able to be inserted into my SQL db (via $_POST) with no problems, however, I would like to be able to use some of the other jquery examples listed on Mr. Thornton's site - but none of them (with the exception of the Basic Example - which seems to be only partially working) will work. Attached is the pertinent code. Any input would be much appreciated. Also, I tried going through this tutorial (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-jquery) and hence I tried adding the script (note: 10/9/17 https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js) but that didn't seem to have any effect.

```
    <?php
    //DOCTYPE begins header.html
    include_once("includes/header.html");

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <!--<style media="screen"></style>-->

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Crime Stoppers</title>

        <!--added 10/9/17-->
        <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
        <!--<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>-->

        <!--Austin's Original links and scripts-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles/styles.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./jquery/css/excite-bike/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./jquery/css/excite-bike/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./jquery/timepicker/jquery.timepicker.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery/timepicker/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#basicExample').timepicker();
    //            $('#scrollDefaultExample').timepicker({ 'scrollDefault': 'now' });
    //            $('#setTimeExample').timepicker();
    //            $('#setTimeButton').on('click', function (){
    //                $('#setTimeExample').timepicker('setTime', new Date());
    //            });
            });
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="header" align="center"><img src="./images/document.png" alt="header"/></div>

    <div align="center">

            <h1>Crime Stoppers Report</h1>

            <form class="formLayout" action="Violent.php" method="POST">

                <fieldset class="table">
                    <legend>Crime</legend>
                      <div class="tr">
                        <div class="td right">Date of Call:</div>
                        <div class="td"><input type="text" class="datepicker" name="callDate"></div>
                        <div class="td right">Time of Call:</div>
                        <div class="td"><input type="text" id="basicExample" name="callTime"></div>
                    </div>
               </fieldset>
           </form>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code displays the scroll bar for me, as well as enables basic timepicker, as well as the set date example.  Its not every example, but will get you on your way

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Crime Stoppers</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/timepicker@1.11.12/jquery.timepicker.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/timepicker@1.11.12/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#basicExample').timepicker();
            $('#setTimeButton').on('click', function () {
                $('#basicExample').timepicker('setTime', new Date());
            })
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header" align="center"><img src="./images/document.png" alt="header" /></div>
    <div align="center">
        <h1>Crime Stoppers Report</h1>
        <form class="formLayout" action="Violent.php" method="POST">
            <fieldset class="table">
                <legend>Crime</legend>
                <div class="tr">
                    <div class="td right">Date of Call:</div>
                    <div class="td"><input type="text" class="datepicker" name="callDate"></div>
                    <div class="td right">Time of Call:</div>
                    <div class="td"><input type="text" id="basicExample" name="callTime"></div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        <button id="setTimeButton">Set current time</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for your prompt response. I went ahead and prepended my functions with $(document).ready and still no change. Then, I went ahead and copied over the two scripts and links you included. After doing so, my functions no longer worked at all (I commented out the <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>) and my functions are working again, though the timepicker is still not working. :-/

Comment: Okay, so I completely scrapped my html header and simply copied and pasted your header in (I did preserve/carryover my <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles/styles.css"/>), now I'm at least getting a srollbar, though when I click on the 'Set current time', the current time flashes in the box, then disappears. I'm able to select the time from the drop down and it populates the field and stays. Another oddity is that my dropdown has a vertical line ending each time selection compared to the snippet you provided which is 'clean'. Weird.

Comment: Not sure what is wrong, the code I pasted works.  Run it by clicking 'Run Code Snippet'.  I suspect its any code you have that is extra than what I posted.  Just start over clean with the snippet, then add from there.

Comment: I'm surprised you haven't marked my question as an answer, as it is a fully working solution to your problem.  Just start with the code posted, then add from there.

Comment: Yessir, I see how your snippet works - very nice! However, when I copy and paste your snippet into my header it seems to work partially however the 'Set current time' button isn't working (the current time flashes and disappears). I also lose all of my CSS and other (working) functions.

Comment: That's because you're adding my code to your code.  I don't know how you are combining them.  What is the final result after you add my code to your code?  You would have to re-post the whole thing then we would have to go from there

Comment: Okay, I am a newbie (no doubt you guessed that) and I'm only doing this project part time as studies allow (full-time college student). The code I'm working with was developed before I arrived on the scene, so I'm trying to figure out how it all works. I've been exploring the jquery folder that is referenced in my original header trying to make sense of it (it basically has a bunch of css, .png(s), .gif(s), .xml(s), a development-bundle folder with a bunch of stuff in it (json files), a timepicker folder, etc. Not sure where to start on modifying/improving the existing function library.

Comment: We can goto private message if you want, they frown on extended discussions in commemts

Comment: Definitely. Not sure how to go to private message.

Comment: I guess there isn't.  Was getting this message though.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95937/why-must-we-avoid-discussions-in-comments

Comment: Hmm.. I've had one chat session before: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155679/discussion-between-manuel-otto-and-stackboy.

Comment: Looks like you are the only one who has enough points to create new chat room:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms (I simply googled "how to create chat room in stackoverflow")

Comment: Try this first:  navigate in your browser to the js and css file urls referenced in my answer and save them in your project.  Delete all the other css and js  files in your project and just reference the new ones locally.  Either that or just make your code match mine.   You're getting problems with css and is by trying to mix your code and mine.  Just reference what's in the answer and nothing else

Comment: Still no luck.:-/

Comment: Still no suggestions? I deleted the REFERENCES to the CSS and JS files and replaced them with references to the CSS and JS files that I downloaded from the sites you referenced.

Comment: So how did you find the links that you directed me to?

Comment: The jQuery links are hosted by Google on known locations.  The time picker links I looked up on the docs for the project page.  As for why your code still isn't working,  it's hard to say without seeing it.  It has to be exactly like in the working example,  or the css and js files have to be copied and referenced locally in the correct way

Comment: Okay,  I was able to get it working. I needed to change the button to an <input type="button"> because the button element was submitting each time I clicked it (thus losing the time value that was appearing in the box, then disappearing). However, I've given up on using the jquery you helped me with because if I use it, I lose the functionality of the original jqueries (datepickers) that I was using. But many thanks for your help!! Unless you have insight into how I can 'get the best of both worlds.'

Comment: "The time picker links I looked up on the docs for the project page." I'm not following with you on this. By 'project page' are you referring to https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker ? If so, where on the page do you see the docs?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably about calling the JavaScript functions before the document is fully loaded.

```
$(function() {
   $(document).ready(function() {
      // Your code here
   }
});
```

It is always best practice to use JavaScript only when the document is ready (a.k.a. `document.onload` event), replaced by jQuery's `$(document).ready()` event.

Comment: thank you for response. I followed your advice, but no change. :-/